# Is there such a thing as O(n/2) in Big O notation?

Tags: arrays, big-o

I have an array that I am incrementing through by two each time.  Since there are half as many increments, would I say O(n/2) or just O(n) since it's linear?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just `O(n)`. Big-O doesn't care about constant factors. (Or rather, multiplication by an arbitrary finite factor is already a part of the big-O definition, so specifying another constant factor within it is redundant.) More technically:

Definition: `f(x) = O(g(x))` when `x -> infinity` if and only if there exist a real `M` and positive real `x0` such that `|f(x)| <= M * |g(x)|` for all `x > x0`.

But if your `g(x)` is actually `1/2 h(x)`, then you can make a new `M'` such that `M = 2 M'`, and express it this way: `|f(x)| <= 2M' * |1/2 h(x)| = M'|h(x)|` - i.e. `O(n)` is equivalent to `O(n/2)`.

To put it another way: big-O says how the performance changes with the change in input size. If you double your array, you double your time - whether you read every element, or every other.

This is also one of the dangers of applying Big-O on finite data sizes: if you know that you have ten thousand rows and are choosing between two algorithms, it is not necessarily the case that `O(n)` will be better than `O(n^2)` - maybe the latter has a very fast time-per-cycle while the former studies each element for minutes at a time. The only place where big-O is relevant is a measure of *scaling*.

Answer (score 2):

The set of functions described by the notation Ο(n) is exactly the same as the set of functions described by the notation Ο(n/2), which is in fact exactly the same as the set of functions described by the notation Ο(c*n) for *any* constant finite c.

tl;dr: doesn't matter, both mean the same.

Answer (score 2):

By definition O(n/2) is not a correct way of defining it. Even an O(n/100) would not make a difference in terms of the notation.

In terms of practical terms, if you iterate N/2 it will be better in terms of speed (twice as fast), but it will *not* be considered better than O(n); using Big O notation.

Generally, you want do everything possible to reduce its Big(O), for example to linear at O(1). If that is not possible, only then should you optimize to N/2 iterations, or N/4, and so forth.