# Why the Big-O is O(n) and not O(n/2) of this code

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I am trying to understand the Big-O of algorithms.

I found this code online and I wasn't able to understand how the Big-O was calculated for it:

```
void printFirstItemThenFirstHalfThenSayHi100Times(int arr[], int size)
{
    printf("First element of array = %d\n",arr[0]); % O(1)
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i++)                % O(n/2)
    {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)                   % O(100), which is a constant
    {
        printf("Hi\n");
    }
}
```

It says ([big-o-with-examples](https://developerinsider.co/big-o-notation-explained-with-examples/)) that, the big-O is O(N)! why?

I see that we have a constant at the beginning O(1), then O(n/2), and finally O(100). Why the Big-O is O(N) and not O(N/2)?

Comment: O(n) is identical to O(n/2).

Comment: When the number of iterations double when you double the size and triple when you triple the size it is `O(n)`.

Comment: ... which is identical to O(10000000n), a constant factor does not matter, that is the point of the O notation.

Comment: Big o of something means this is something you can dominate (in abs) with a * something . These are order of magnitudes that's why you don't care of the factor

Comment: Thanks, guys! @luk2302 I wasn't asking about the 100 (second loop), I was asking why not N/2? anyway, got it now.

Comment: Watch out with the ! ... n! is something entirely different.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Big-O(n) == Big-O(1/2 * n)`, drop the constant factor.
See [Is there such a thing as O(n/2) in Big O notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853811/is-there-such-a-thing-as-on-2-in-big-o-notation)